# Connection between Java and Baidu Maps

Tags: java, xml, json

I have a java code using Baidu Maps Geocode API to retrieve longitude/latitude info of an address. The problem is that the answer (an inputStream with XML/JSon format) is always the same: status = 1 and msg = Internal Service Error.

At first I thought it could be a bad url created by my code, but that same url works fine in any browser.

I add my code so you can see if there's something wrong with it that I didn't notice:

---

```
    private static final String URLDIR = "http://api.map.baidu.com";
    private static final String URLPATH = "/geocoder/v2/?";

    public void getGeocoding(String address)
      throws IOException
    {
      String HostName = AutoCompletar.getProxyName();
      int HostPort = AutoCompletar.getProxyPort();
      String uri = "";
      String uriEncode = "";

      this.latitude = "";
      this.longitude = "";
      this.estado = "";
      System.out.print("\nCalculate lat,lng: " + address + "\n");
      System.out.print("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
      try {
        uri = URLDIR + URLPATH;
        String uriQuery = "address=" + address;
        uriQuery = uriQuery + "&output=xml" + "&ak=" + baiduKey;
        System.out.println("uriQuery: " + uriQuery);
        uriEncode = uri + uriQuery;
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", HostName); 
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(HostPort));
        URL bmap = new URL(uriEncode);
        HttpURLConnection yc = null;
        if (HostName == null || HostName.equals("")) {
            yc = (HttpURLConnection) bmap.openConnection();
        } else {
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(HostName,HostPort));

            yc = (HttpURLConnection) bmap.openConnection(proxy);
        }

        //yc.connect();
        BufferedReader in = 
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

        InputSource inputXml = new InputSource(in);
        try {
          SimpleParser xmlParser = new SimpleParser(inputXml);
          System.out.println(xmlParser.toString());
          this.estado = xmlParser.nodeValue("/GeocoderSearchResponse/status/text()");
          System.out.print("Status: " + this.estado + "\n");
          if ("0".equals(this.estado)) {
            this.latitude = xmlParser.nodeValue("/GeocoderSearchResponse/result/location/lat/text()");
            this.longitude = xmlParser.nodeValue("/GeocoderSearchResponse/result/location/lng/text()");
            System.out.print("lat,lng: " + this.latitude + "," + this.longitude + "\n");
          } else {
            throw new IOException(this.estado);
          }
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          System.out.println("Status :" + ex.getMessage());
          dispatchMessage(ABORTED);
        }

        in.close();
      }
      catch (UnsupportedEncodingException Ur) {
        System.out.println("Error UnsupportedEncodingException. " + Ur.getMessage());
        System.out.println(uri);
        System.out.println("URI Encode: " + uriEncode);
        dispatchMessage(ABORTED);
      }
      catch (IOException Ur) {
        System.out.println("Error geocoding from Google. " + Ur);
        dispatchMessage(ABORTED);
      }
    }
```

---

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Baidu Maps requires you to register the SDK, are you sure you did that first?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think this is because your request doesn't have `User-Agent` header, some servers have this policy in order to not send data to robots as your application.
As this

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "<<a_user_aganet/such_as_chrome>>");//generally
//OR
yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "<<a_user_aganet/such_as_chrome>>");
```

First it's better to contact and look up for some API(btb) approach for getting info from the target server.
You may fool teh server by some fake user-agent, but if the target server was designed very tough, after some serial requests it might challenge you by a captcha.

Comment: Thank you very much for your early response. I'm afraid to say that  your solution didn't work. But it's something I will take into account in the future.